# Convert Eclipse java project (with java source folder) to gradle project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I want to migrate all my **java projects** (223 projects) to **gradle project**. 
I'm using the Gradle Eclipse plugin, developed by the SpringSource STS team.

Currently, all my java projets is strutured like that:

```
MyProjet/
+- src/log
    +- some.package.log
    +- some.package.log.A
+- src/tools/core
    +- some.package
    +- some.package.tools.B
    +- some.package.tools.C
+- src/tools/graph
    +- some.package.graph
+- src/tests
    +- some.package.test.D
+- src/someModule

+- otherDirectories
```

src/log, src/tools/core, src/tools/graph, src/tests and src/someModule are **java source folders**.

After converting the project to gradle (via Configure -> "Convert to Gradle Project..."), all java source folders become packages.

Also, the matter is that all declared packages in java classes must be modified. For example, Eclipse tell me that: 
The declared package "some.package.test.tools.A" does not match the expected package "tests.some.package.test.tools.A"

Eclipse give me the possibility to change the package declaration of a class. But I must do that for all classes (sometimes more than 100 classes for one project).

**I want to know if there is a way to convert a java project (with java source folder) to a gradle project, without impacting all packages (I would like to avoid the operation that consist in modifiyng all classes)**

Thank you in advance for help or any advices.

Naike.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to write Gradle build script(s) and, among other things, declare your source directory structure there. (You don't have to change the source directory structure or any package statements.) "Convert to Gradle Project" won't do this for you. It's merely a way to activate Gradle support for the project, which will make Eclipse use information contained in the Gradle build scripts, allow you to execute a Gradle build from the IDE, etc.

Comment: The matter is when I use "Convert to Gradle Project", all Java source folders become java packages (and some of them are restructured because of their name). Even if I put all the java source folders in the sourceSets configuration of my build.gralde, when the migration is done, java source folders are converted to packages and the structure of this packages is not the same that before. So I need to update all package declaration.

Comment: Updating package declarations is the wrong solution. First you should concentrate on getting the Gradle build to work (no IDE). Then, instead of converting an existing IDE project, you can import the Gradle build into the IDE, which will create a new IDE project.

Comment: Ok, I will try this now. I've just installed gradle on my ubuntu to test that.

Comment: When I configure my project without the IDE, it's ok. I can compile my project, generate the jar,etc. But When I import it in my Eclipse, the previous problem has come back. Eclipse underline all packages (and classes) and tell me that there are problems with declaration packages (but I can execute my gradle tasks in Eclipse and it works fine). Any other good suggestions?

Comment: How *exactly* do you import the project?

Comment: To import the project, I add the eclipse plugin to my build.gradle. After that, I run "gradle eclipse". 
Then, with Eclipse, File -> Import project -> Gradle Project. Is this the wrong way to do?

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake in my build.gradle. I forgot to declare the structure as it was in the previous java project. So, it's work now. Thank you for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way you can do is to change "source folder" under, by doing following steps:

1. Open Project preferences
2. Open Java Build Path
3. Under "Source" tab there is "Source folders on build path". You can customize it so that "src" is a source folder and not the "/" one (because I guess that has changed after project migration).

I hope that helps!

Comment: By default, the configuration of source folders are OK. When the migration is done, all my previous java source folders become packages and are stored under a 'src' folder. In the Java Build Path, this is automatically updated. 
When I do "Convert to Gradle project", java source folders are converted to packages but without keeping the structure of the previous java source folders.